# Promises: WebdriverIO UI tests are running only on Chrome, not working on Firefox, Safari

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, es6-promise, webdriver-io

I have created the test.page.js where I have set elements on the page. I want to find the Add button. This is my code:

```
import Page from './page';

class TestPage extends Page {
  get addButton() {
    return browser.element('#add-button > a');
  }
  getAddButton() {
    return this.addButton.getText();
  }
```

According to documentation, the below example should work but it doesn't. It returns the *pending promise*:

```
import Page from './page';

class LoginPage extends Page {

    get username()  { return browser.element('#username'); }
```

In my test.spec.js file I am asserting this element using chai as promise extension to Chai library:

```
import testPage from '../pageobjects/test.page';

it('should validate if Add button exists', (done) => {
  testPage.getAddButton().should.eventually.be.equal('Create a new thing').notify(done);
 });
```

and it works on Chrome but fails on Firefox or Safari. I think I am doing something wrong with locating the elements, my version varies from the documentation one. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes not with your element selectors, which as far as I can tell are written all correctly, but in how you're using Chai.

WebdriverIO does some special magic to where you shouldn't need to use the 'eventually' keyword. Try this assertion out: `testPage.getAddButton().should.equal('Create a new thing')`

I created a test example using a similar idea for you to try running:
http://try.learnwebdriverio.com/share/dyhVLxYf897he6l4

Comment: That was it, I just had a problem with using Chai, the problem was not with WebdriverIO itself. Thank you @klamping

Comment: Glad it fixed it!